# SQLite: Foreign Key "ON DELETE SET NULL" action not getting triggered

Tags: sql, sqlite, express, knex.js, objection.js

**Why is `ON DELETE SET NULL` failing when deleting a row via the application code, but it behaves correctly when manually executing an SQL statement?**

I have a todo table and a category table. The todo table has a `category_id` foreign key that references `id` in the category table, and it was created with the "ON DELETE SET NULL" action.

```sql
create table `category` (
  `id` integer not null primary key autoincrement,
  `name` varchar(255) not null
);
```

```sql
create table `todo` (
  `id` integer not null primary key autoincrement,
  `title` varchar(255) not null,
  `complete` boolean not null default '0',
  `category_id` integer,
  foreign key(`category_id`) references `category`(`id`) on delete SET NULL on update CASCADE
);
```

I also have an endpoint in my application that allows users to delete a category.

```js
categoryRouter.delete('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params
  await req.context.models.Category.delete(id)
  return res.status(204).json()
})
```

This route successfully deletes categories, but the problem is that related todo items are not getting their `category_id` property set to null, so they end up with a category id that no longer exists. Strangely though, if I open up my database GUI and manually execute the query to delete a category... `DELETE FROM category WHERE id=1`... the "ON DELETE SET NULL" hook is successfully firing. Any todo item that had `category_id=1` is now set to null.

Full application source can be found [here](https://github.com/johncmunson/todo-app).

Comment: Have you enabled foreign key support? [Enabling Foreign Key Support](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable)

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out, thanks to MikeT.

So apparently SQLite by default has foreign key support turned off. WTF!

To enable FKs, I had to change my code from this...

```js
const knex = Knex(knexConfig.development)
Model.knex(knex)
```

to this...

```
const knex = Knex(knexConfig.development)
knex.client.pool.on('createSuccess', (eventId, resource) => {
  resource.run('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON', () => {})
})
Model.knex(knex)
```

---

Alternatively, I could have done this inside of the `knexfile.js`...

```
module.exports = {
 development: {
   client: 'sqlite3',
   connection: {
     filename: './db.sqlite3'
   },
   pool: {
     afterCreate: (conn, cb) => {
       conn.run('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON', cb)
     }
   }
 },
 staging: {},
 production: {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI and other people who stumbled across a similar problem, you need `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON` not only for the child table but also for the parent table.

When I set `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON` only for a program which handles the child table, `ON UPDATE CASCADE` was enabled but `ON DELETE SET NULL` was still disabled. At last I found out that I forgot `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON` for another program which handles the parent table.